# Range and increment of data in Matlab

Tags: plot, matlab, matlab-figure, figure, curve

Lets consider I am given a plot and I do not have its x and y vectors but I would like to extract them from the plot in Matlab.  Also I am interested to know the increment of data (step size) in both horizontal and vertical axis(x and y axis). 
I was thinking of using :

```
h=gca             % Get current axis
X=get(h,'xdata');
Y=get(h,'ydata');
stepsize=X(2)-X(1);
```

But these command produce an error message that :
xdata and ydata are not accessible property of axis. Any suggestion how to find the x and y vectors for any given curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, these are the two things you want to know:

1. You have a figure containing a plot of some arbitrary 2d line, whose `x_vec, y_vec` are unknown to you and you want to extract them from the figure\axes.
2. You want to get the `xtick` and `ytick` positions used in the figure you have.

---

The reason your code does not work, is because you're trying to access a property of the `axes`, whereas what you *want* to access is the property of the `line` (i.e. the curve in the plot).

To solve your **first** problem, you can resort to the following methods:

**Manual**: using the `edit plot` figure tool you can get to the `XData` and `YData` properties of the line, in the following manner:

[image: How to get to a line's XData manually]

**Programmatic**: you need to find the `handle` (i.e. pointer) to the line, and then use your code on *that* handle (and not on `gca`):

```
%// If there's only one entity (child) in the axes:
hLine = get(gca,'Children');
%// If there's more than one child:
hChildren = findobj(gca,'Type','line');
hLine = hChildren(1); %// Or any other logic you need to pick the correct line
%// Then comes your code:
xD = get(hLine,'XData'); yD = get(hLine,'YData');
```

---

For the **second** problem you can use `gca` to get `XTick` and `YTick`:

```
xT = get(gca,'XTick'); yT = get(gca,'YTick');
```

---

To get the step size I'd suggest simply using `diff()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand your question. You mean get x and y data of a curve? If yes, then maybe it'll help looking into 'ginput'.

For example, picking 10 points from a figure window you can use the following command

```
[x,y] = ginput(10)
```